# How can I send an image to a virtual camera in my program?

Tags: image, camera

Is it possible to send an image to a virtual camera in C/C++ programming? If so, how can I create a virtual camera in windows (using any application is also acceptable)? and what is the simplest solution to send an image to the camera?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure I understand this! Normally cameras take pictures and send them to us. Why would we take a picture and send it to a camera? What is the camera going to do with it? Or has it got a built-in projector? I'm confused.

Comment: What kind of device are you trying to communicate with? Are you talking about some kind of virtual drive?

Comment: @mark-setchell, I want to control the output of a virtual cam.

Comment: @nyerguds, I want a (virtual) camera which can be detected by other programs. Actually, I want to tell the cam what it must show on its output.

Comment: That didn't answer my question at all... how is this kind of device typically communicated with?